# Alert message button, with restrictions to go further to next viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Hello I am making a ViewController with a PickerView that has age restrictions. I made it with the alert and age restrictions but I need it to deny access to next ViewController if the user isn't old enough.

Made my code like this, I guess its in the `Else true` I need some more code, but I'm not sure tho. I hope a kind soul can help me :)

```
@IBAction func verificerKnap(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Creating the age restriction for the datepicker
    let dateOfBirth = datoPicker.date

    let today = NSDate()

    let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

    let age = gregorian.components([.Year], fromDate: dateOfBirth, toDate: today, options: [])

    if age.year < 18 {

        // Alert controller som sender en advarsel hvis personen er under 18år
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Age restriction", message:
            "This app requires an age of 18+", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    } else {

        true
```

Comment: So this verificerKnap is an touch down event on some button i presume? Just segue to your next view controller when you have this `true`

Comment: Yeah, the meaning of the button is that it needs to take me further to next viewcontroller that i have made, but only if the person is 18 years or older. I've made a modal segue but it seems like even if i place age below 18 it still justs goes further. Any ideas ? :)

Comment: What do you mean by goes further? If age is under 18 it should just show the dialog with an Okay button and do nothing else. Have you tried using breakpoints to figure out what gets called when in this method?

Comment: What i mean with the button is that if the person is 18 or older, it needs to go further to next viewcontroller i made in my storyboard. i placed a modal segue in the storyboard to my next viewcontroller but it seems to pass whether the person is 1 or 100 years. I hope im not confusing you too much.

Comment: It doesn't magically pass to your next view controller - it must happen somewhere in this verificerKnap method. Can you show me the rest of it?

Comment: Sure i can, what do you want me to send to ya ?.the other viewcontroller i have, is in another viewcontroller.swift file i created.

Comment: No no, where do you call your performSegueWithIdentifier or something?

Comment: Ahh thats what i haven't made, i guess thats what i'm needing?. But i am not sure what to write. My guess would be something like? self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyotherViewController?" sender:self]

Comment: Yeah. In the else of the age checking. I still don't understand how you get to the next view controller by pressing this button though.

Comment: i guess something like this then? My other viewController.swift file is called ViewControllerSearch
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
     
            
        } else {
            
            true
            
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(ViewControllerSearch, sender: self)

Comment: `else  { self.performSegueWithIdentifier(ViewControllerSearch, sender: self)   }` should work.

Comment: its not working, i get the error "Cannot convert value of type viewControllerSearch.type to expected argument type string.

Comment: yeah, the identifier should be a string. The one you should set on the storyboard. so self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewId", sender: self)

Comment: Okay, i dont get any error. but i dont get prompted if i pick age below 18 :S Can the problem be because i use Modal Segue? do i need to use something else in my storyboard to refer further ? made it like this.

 } else {
            
            true
            
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewControllerSearch", sender: self)

Answer (score 0):

You can present an UIAlertController which asks if you are 18 years or older. Than link 2 buttons "Ok" and "Cancel" and add delegates for those:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: "Are you 18 years or older?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { 
    (action) in
    print("User is not yet >18")
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { 
    (action) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.presentViewController(desired_view_controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
// ...
}
```

based on: http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/